# How to capitalize the common letters of two words?

Tags: java

I'm trying to capitalize the common letters of two words. Does anyone know why my code doesn't work?

It says:

```
Main.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        char character = words.charAt(i);
                              ^
  symbol:   method charAt(int)
  location: variable words of type String[]
```

The code is:

```java
    int word2;
    int space_count = 0;
 

    //get input
    System.out.println ("Input two words: ");
    int word = sameletters.nextInt();
    
    String words[] = new String[word];

    //find the begining of the second word
    for(int i = 0, n = words.length; i<n; i++)
    {
        char character = words.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isWhitespace(character))
        {
            word2 = i + 1;
            space_count++;
        }
    }

    //validate the input.
    for(int i = 0, n = words.length; i<n; i++)
    {
    if(space_count != 1)
    {
        System.out.println ("MUST CONTAIN 2 WORDS\n");
        break;
    }
    }

    //loop for the first word
    for (int i = 0, n = word2 - 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        //loop for the second word
        for (int j = word2, x = words.length; j < x; j++)
        {
            //compare the letters
            if(words[i] == words[j])
            {
                words[i] = words[i].toUpperCase();
                words[j] = words[j].toUpperCase();
            }
        }
    }

    //print output
    System.out.println ("\n" + words);
    sameletters.close();
}
}
```

Comment: `String words[]` is an array of multiple Strings. You are trying to call a method of String on that array: `words.charAt(i)` which can't work because words isn't a single String but multiple Strings.  You first need to get an element of that array and then you can call the charAt method on that single String. eG. `words[0].charAt(0)` will get the first character of your first String, `words[9].charAt(4)` would get the fifth character of the 10th String of your array.

Comment: I should probably also mention that your code to get input makes little sense. You tell the User `"Input two words: "` but then ask for input of a single number. You then use that single number to initialize your String array but never fill that array with anything. If you want your user to really be able to input 2 words you need to use another method like `nextLine()`.